# Printing out element values from XmlReader

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I want to upload an *xml file*, and then go through the whole file and print out of every value from each of the elements in the file.

So, I have this xml file:

```
<Student>
        <Surname>Adrien</Surname>
        <Lastname>Wilsen</Lastname 
        <School>LUA</School>
        <GPA>10.5</GPA>
</Student>
```

Now, with `XmlReader` I want to go through each element of the file, and print out the value in console. Here is my code:

```
        XmlReader xmlReader;
        string xmlFilePath = @"C:\Student.xml";

        xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFilePath);

        while(xmlReader.Read())
        {
            if(xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                string val = xmlReader.Value;
                Console.WriteLine(val);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

When I debug my code, I see that it enter my `if statement`, but when I take out the `value` and save it to my variable **"val"**, it gets the value of an empty string every time. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is your element a text element?

Write out the `xmlReader.Name` to check what your are writing out.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.value?view=netframework-4.8

You should use in your if statement `XmlNodeType.Text`:

```
if(xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
{
   string val = xmlReader.Value;
   Console.WriteLine(val);
}
```

For `XmlNodeType.Element` you can print out element name:

```
if(xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
{
   string val = xmlReader.Name;
   Console.WriteLine(val);
}
```